# Is there a way to programmatically grab the participants for a single meeting occurrence in a recurrence meeting series from outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I am trying to get participants from a meeting occurrence that is in a meeting series and when I updated participants for the single occurrence, Is there any way to grab the participants from the particular appointment item when inspector is opened. When I try it was returning all the participants for the meeting series.

```
void inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
        {
            var appointmentItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            if (appointmentItem != null)
            {
                var startTime = appointmentItem.Start;
                var endTime = appointmentItem.End;
                var recipients = appointmentItem.Recipients;
            }
        }
```

here for the start time and end time appointment was returning current occurrence start and end times.

Answer (score 0):

For each recipient you need to check the response status:

```
private void CheckAttendeeStatus(Outlook.AppointmentItem appt)
{
    if (appt != null)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in appt.Recipients)
        {
            switch (recip.MeetingResponseStatus)
            {
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseAccepted:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Accepted: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseTentative:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Tentative: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseDeclined:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Declined: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseOrganized:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Organizer: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseNone:
                    Debug.WriteLine("None: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
                case Outlook.OlResponseStatus.olResponseNotResponded:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Not responded: " + recip.Name);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also use the [AppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.requiredattendees) and [AppointmentItem.OptionalAttendees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.optionalattendees) properties to get a semicolon-delimited string of required and optional attendee names for the meeting appointment.